# How to comment out yml file for docker4drupal to install Drupal 7 on Windows 10 64bit

Tags: 7

I followed all instructions and got the code for yml file here:

```
https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L4
```

I commented out line 33:

```
image: wodby/drupal:7-5.6-3.3.2
```

Then I tried to install on:

```
  http://drupal.docker.localhost:8000/core/install.php
```

Then I got this errors:

```
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php on line 50
```

Drupal 8 install works fine, but I need this for Drupal 7 what am I doing wrong?

And are there any other yml files I can use that has D7, php and Sql all ready to go  in a consolidated container like the wodby docker4drupal?

Comment: Can you show us the lines that you commented in docker-compose.yml file. Basic commenting in docker-compose.yml file is a '#' in front of any line which you like to comment.

Comment: You can use DrupalVM to do Drupal 7. Frankly for local development I’ve found Docker to be frustrating.

Comment: I think so, reason I'm trying this is that I'm using Xampp portable, works fine, but I'm having windows folder permission issues because of a corrupted Win 10 install, so I thought I would try docker to save time....however, seems like reformating windows will be less trouble than docker, so I might just do that. Kevin, do you think Xampp is better than aquia dev desktop? I need portability and speed, I've noticed that Xampp on my i5-8400 with 16 gigs of Ram runs super fast, like 1/5 second for some pages, makes developing feel like static HTML loading pages;)

Comment: DrupalVM > Acquia DD

Comment: I was never a fan of Aquia dev desktop. I found it to be a limited version of Xampp or Mamp. If you want to experiment with Docker and Drupal, I'd suggest DruDock (https://github.com/4AllDigital/DruDockCli), it's supper easy, and handles installing Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 without any yml fiddling.

Comment: @Kevin, try my answer 